# SQL Query Error in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

This sounds very simplistic, but I have no idea why the following code won't create a table, and just throws an error. The error just says "Could not execute update one" (as specified in the catch statement). The code is:

```
sqlString = "CREATE TABLE TEMP " +
            "(Student_name varchar(30) NOT NULL, " +
            "Student_id char(5) NOT NULL, " +
            "Num_exam smallint NOT NULL, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY (Student_id))";

try {
  stmt.executeUpdate(sqlString);
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("Could not execute update one");
  stmt.close();
  return;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Edit: printStackTrace results in

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:931)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1707)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1670)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:310)
    at application.busyStudents(application.java:282)
    at application.main(application.java:67)
```

Comment: Print out the stacktrace and paste it here. Can't do much without specific error.

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block and post ([edit]) the output.

Comment: You can get more info from the error using e.printStackTrace() and other functions such as e.getCause() etc.

Comment: Can you try modify the query like this: Student_name varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ....... AND remove PRIMARY KEY (Student_id) at the end ?

Comment: I think you already created a table with name "TEMP". Change the table name and try execute the query. Thats why you need to show your printStackTrace()

Comment: That's great, thank you. I didn't know about that printStackTrace() ! I'll make sure I use it from now on so I don't have to post silly things like this again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the `sqlString` changing the name of table:

```
 sqlString = " CREATE TABLE TEMP1 " +
             "( Student_name varchar(30) NOT NULL, " +
             " Student_id char(5) NOT NULL, " +
             " Num_exam smallint NOT NULL, " +
             " PRIMARY KEY (Student_id))";
```